# How less command shows output on stdout

Tags: linux, bash, shell, less-unix

I tried less command to view files in a zip file and to my surprise when I was done with the output, all my previous screen data was still present (which is not the case if i use more command for viewing a file content).

how does less command able to do this ?

Please refer the below images for more information..

before running the less command below is the terminal content,

[image]

After running the less command below is the terminal content,

[image]

How is less able to retain the terminal information unlike other commands like cat or more or zcat ?!

Any reference on this would also be of great help !

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This might help: [Show output on another “screen” and return to normal when done](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27941/74329)

Comment: thanks for the link.. this is the answer to the question - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27953